# Grafana filter on unindexed ElasticSearch field (zeros) so they aren't shown in Table Panel

Tags: elasticsearch, grafana

We have a table that shows warning counts in our services, but we aren't interested in those that are zero.

Because the warning count is a un-indexed number (integer) we can't include it as a filter criteria.  How can these be removed from our dashboard?

Comment: I am not familliar with Grafana, but ES has an "exists" query which might be what you are looking for. So, if you can integrate this in your dashboard (or find that Grafana functionality that uses it) it might help you.

Comment: Here's an idea: https://community.grafana.com/t/how-to-query-for-null-values/799/4

Answer (score 1):

I am not familliar with Grafana, but ES has an ["exists" query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.3/query-dsl-exists-query.html) which might be what you are looking for. So, if you can integrate this in your dashboard (or find that Grafana functionality that uses it) it might help you. For your information (because Grafana might use this as well like it is) you can use "exists" query in the Lucene query dsl as `_exists_`. A practical example - `_exists_:warning_count_field`. More about this [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.3/query-dsl-query-string-query.html#_field_names)

The same question seems to have been asked before in a more or less similar form: https://community.grafana.com/t/how-to-query-for-null-values/799/5 and the answer is the same as the one I posted above: the `_exists_` filter/query.

Comment: How would you use _exists_ comparing to a zero from Grafana?